# Processing bytearray shows no difference

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, arrays

I wanted to write a simple processing function.

It should run like this:

- Load a Jpeg
- Convert it to Bitmap
- save bitmap as byte array
- process
- data convert back to bitmap show Image.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
ImageView imgView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    AssetFileDescriptor asf;
    String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Test/"
            + "DSC00751.JPG";
    Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // Convert image so it can be stored in byteArray
    map.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bout);
    byte[] array = bout.toByteArray();

    // Process image.
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < 0) {
            array[i] = (byte) 200;
        }
    }

    // Convert result and display
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I get a whitescreen in return. No matter how my processing code looks like.
I tried using foreach(byte b : array) before, but this always returned the original image.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your also doing image processing in an activity which will block the main ui thread; you should be doing this in a separate thread and update the imageView upon completion.

Comment: thats just for fun, I want to test how this can be done anyway.

Comment: What did you try to process? Image processing with byte??

Comment: I thought thats how it's done?

Comment: If you want to process image, try to work with pixels, not byte!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 // Process image.
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < 0) {
            array[i] = (byte) 200;
        }
    }
```

in this code you are changing image bytes!! so thats why it appears white!!
what else?

---

anyway, if you need to process an image you need to do it like that :

```
    Bitmap bitmap =...;
    int[] pixels = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];

    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
```

now you have the pixels array of the image (int[])

Comment: Not Yet. My images size is 1536 x 2048 , thats 3145728 pixels. My arrays length is 1838103, how can this be? I used to work with UInt in c# and this has been no problem so far.

Comment: yes sure, note the `CompressFormat = JPEG` and the `Compress Value set to 100` in your code `map.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bout);`, this will low the quality of you image, and another thing, the result byte array doesn't present 1 Pixel in 1 byte, no.

Comment: so one byte represents more than one pixel and every "pixel" in this array will be displayed more than one time?

Comment: mmm, i cant figure that out, but in JPEG as i know, the whole file bytes relay on each other, to represent the image.